# Treetop ignores methods defined in grammar

Tags: ruby, treetop

I'm trying to parse a percentage with treetop. I wrote the following grammar:

```
grammar Numerals
  rule percentage
    (decimal "%") {
      def to_f
        decimal.to_f / 100
      end
    }
  end

  rule decimal
    sign [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]* {
      def to_f
        text_value.to_f
      end
    }
  end

  rule sign
    ('+'/'-')? 
  end
end
```

This matches correctly, but for some reason the `to_f` method on the root node is missing in the result.

When I checked the code generated by tt, it had created two modules for the percentage nodes, only one of which was used in the rest of the code:

```
module Percentage0
  def decimal
    elements[0]
  end
end

module Percentage1
  def to_f
    decimal.to_f / 100
  end
end
```

Percentage1 never appears anywhere else in the code, while Percentage0 is used on the correct nodes

```
r0 = instantiate_node(SyntaxNode,input, i0...index, s0)
r0.extend(Percentage0)
```

On the other hand, the `to_f` method on `decimal` works fine (also two modules, but both are used to extend the node). I can't find what is different about its definition, that causes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to remove the parentheses from the root rule.

Also, for the decimal rule you should probably use a `+` instead of a `*` after the decimal; you'll want at least one number there.

```
grammar Numerals
  rule percentage
    decimal "%" {
      def to_f
        decimal.to_f / 100
      end
    }
  end

  rule decimal
    sign [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]+ {
      def to_f
        text_value.to_f
      end
    }
  end

  rule sign
    ('+'/'-')? 
  end
end
```

Comment: Removing the parens helped. Can you explain, why these cause the module not to be used?

Comment: I'm actually not sure honestly. It seems like kind of a mystery to me as well. It might have something to do with the fact that it's the root node? I know that the syntax node seems to show up differently without it though.

Comment: There can be a module inside the parentheses as well as outside, but the outer one never gets extended. This is a known bug in the Treetop compiler.